# Increment number on insert into?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here's my dilemma,

I have the following columns:

ID_C int and NAME varchar

Problem is that ID_C is not set to auto-increment because it's linked to another table with the information on that particular ID_C number. So it cannot auto-increment without having the number in there first, that's why it's not set for auto-increment.

How can I do

```
INSERT INTO Table (ID_C, name)
VALUES (<<This place should query for the last item and increment on the result>>,'Tom B. Erichsen')
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO [Table](ID_C, name) SELECT MAX(ID_C)+1, 'Tom B. Erichsen' FROM [Table]`

Comment: It sounds like you need rethink your table structure.  If the IDs are linked they should be one table or one ID should be a foreign key to the other, with auto-increment on the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [Table](ID_C, name) SELECT MAX(ID_C)+1, 'stack' FROM user_table
```

you can use dml trigger also.(after insert)
refernce

```
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/
```